# HTTPBuilder Get after Javascript has executed

Tags: grails, groovy, screen-scraping, http-get

I've been using `HTTPBuilder` as a way of obtaining a site's HTML content. As an example, this is how I've used it:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)

def root = http.get([:])

// Really just the standard approach.
```

Now this has worked very well for static HTML sites, however I'm now attempting to take data from sites where Javascript is executed on load, which populates the page. For example [this page](http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc-_-ghs-sna15-_-asdacom-dsk-_-hp&#/special_offers/TopOffers).

My question is, does Grails / Groovy have a native way of waiting until all Javascript has executed, before returning the HTML content. If not native, then third party?

**Research I have already attempted**

- I've had a look at libraries that attempt to mock a browser. I thought that if I could get the library to execute the Javascript and only return the result, I could mimic the behaviour I wanted. My research into this has been somewhat limited, as the libraries I have found only give you control over things like your `User-Agent`.

Comment: You may try HtmlUnit/Selenium. Actually I'm using this for testing, but it supports Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using only gets the raw HTML content from the server. So there's nothing to download or execute any code. Selenium might work (or Geb, a Groovy wrapper around it), but the [getPageSource method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29) says that getting the HTML content post-JavaScript depends on the driver. You might find one of the drivers (chrome, firefox, etc.) do return the results post-JavaScript. If that doesn't work, try using PhantomJS ([blog post on what you want](http://stefaanlippens.net/spider-javascript-manipulated-html-with-phantomjs)).

Comment: You're actually onto something here. I'd much rather keep this on the server side have to route it through some front end Javascript. How would I go about specifying the correct driver for *Geb*?

Comment: If you are running this on a server, you should check into HTMLUnit or PhantomJS, as both are headless. PhantomJS is basically headless Chrome (V8 + webkit). HTMLUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is entirely in Java, but not as "compatible" with sites. Other Geb drivers actually launch and manipulate a GUI browser instance. I'd try HTMLUnit first to stay all in Java, if that doesn't work I'd try Geb with PhantomJS driver and getPageSource; if that doesn't return results after DOM, then I'd try shelling out to phantomjs command line with script to print page.content.

Comment: I'll look into these suggestions and get back to you. Thanks mate!